# Error Type 'Observable<{} | T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'. Type '{} | T' is not assignable to type 'T' in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-services, angular6

My project has been migrated from angular-5 to angular-6. In angular-5 it was working fine but i am getting following error

> Type  'Observable<{} | T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. 
>   Type '{} | T' is not assignable to type 'T'

Service code is as following..

```
 getNewUserEndpoint<T>(userObject: any): Observable<T> {

            return this.http.post<T>(this.usersUrl, JSON.stringify(userObject), this.getRequestHeaders())
                .catch(error => {
                    return this.handleError(error, () => this.getNewUserEndpoint(userObject));
                });
        }
```

Comment: I don't know whether it will work or not but it just remove compilation error while changing my code to

getNewUserEndpoint<T>(userObject: any): Observable<T> {

      return this.http.post<T>(this.usersUrl, JSON.stringify(userObject), this.getRequestHeaders())
        .catch(error => {
          return this.getNewUserEndpoint(userObject);
            });
    }